# Tensorflow view graph from model.ckpt.meta file

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a `model.ckpt.meta` file and I just want to view the architecture/graph structure. I can't find how to do this from the `model.ckpt.meta` file.

Following the code thanks to Milan:

```
tf.train.import_meta_graph("./model.ckpt.meta")
for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node:
   print(n)
with tf.Session() as sess:
  writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("./output/", sess.graph)
  writer.close()
```

I get the graph below. But a lot of the architecture is missing.
[image]

EDIT: Woops! I forgot to double click the model. Sorted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can import the meta graph in python with `tf.train.import_meta_graph` and then traverse the nodes in the graph, for example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.train.import_meta_graph("./model.ckpt-200000.meta")
for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node:
   print(n)
```

Once imported, you can make a summary file for Tensorboard, which allows you to visualize the graph nicely:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("./output/", sess.graph)
  writer.close()
```

To see the saved summary file in Tensorboard, run `tensorboard --logdir=./output/`

Comment: Also what is the purpose of `for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node:
   print(n)`

Comment: In the current graph, iterate over all nodes, and print out their text representations.

Comment: When I run the tensorboard command all i get is http://DESKTOP-JQCP6TS:6006/
what am I suppose to do with this?

Comment: ADA.. simply go to your browser and enter http://0.0.0.0:6006 then you will be able to inspect it.